# "Stream XXXXXXXXX is sending an event before being open"error is displayed in my console

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, stream, nsurlconnection

I am using the basic NSURLConnection for communication with server. when a service it hit I am getting the error message like "Stream XXXXXXXX is sending an event before being open" in my console and the UI freezes for a while and the apps goes into non-responding state.

I gone through some questions in SO but I didn't found the solution to resolve this issue.

Can anyone suggest me why this issue occurs and how to resolve it.

Comment: did you got the solution or reason for this...If so pls share it to me